# How to multiply the elements of an array using array#each?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to write a method which takes as its input an array of integers and returns their product. For example:

```
product([1,2,3])    # returns 6
```

I need to do this using `Array#each` and not the inject method. This is what I have come up with, but it seems to be incorrect:

```
def product(array)
  final = 0.0
  array.each do |i|
    final *= i
  end
  return final
end
```

Also, how could I modify this method to return the product of all the odd integers in the array, such that

```
product([1,2,3])     # returns 3, because 2 is even

product([0,-1,-10])  # returns -1, because 0 and -10 are even
```

Comment: I think you mean to initialise `final` to 1

Comment: Just for the record, its a one-liner with reduce/inject: `array.reduce(&:*)`

Comment: It's part of the assignment I was given.

Comment: If you use inject you are actually using each since inject uses the each method :p is that valid?

Answer (score 10):

As Ramon said, just initialize final to 1.0:

```
def product(array)
  final = 1.0
  array.each { |i| final *= i }
  final
end
```

However, in idiomatic Ruby:

```
[1, 2, 3].inject(:*)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question, how would I do this if I want the method to return the product of all the odd integers in the array? For example, product([1,2,3])would return 3, because 2 is even.

Comment: You can first filter the array with find_all, and then use inject to multiply all the elements: [1, 2, 3].find_all { |i| i % 2 == 1 }.inject(:*)

Comment: How would I do it using each? This is what I have so far: array.each do |i|
        if i % 2 == 1 then
        final *= i

Comment: But if you really want to use the .each, just do: array.each { |i| final *= i if i % 2 == 1 }

Comment: Actually you can do it even better by avoiding the modulo (%) operator  using Integer#odd? instead: array.each { |i| final *= i if i.odd? }

Answer (score 5):

```
def find_product(x)
  return x.inject(&:*)
end

x = [5, 6, 7, 10, 15, 18, 32]

find_product(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

**First**

```
for i in arr
 a=i
  for j in arr
   a *=j
  end
 p a
end
```

**Second**

```
for i in arr
  p product = arr.inject(i , :*)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def product(array)
  final = 1.0
  array.each do |i|
    final *= i
  end
  final
end
```